# Есть ли алгоритм который считает сколько пикселей в картинке и определяет цвет каждого пикселя?

Tags: любой-язык

Буду рад, если подскажете код на JS или Python.

Comment: Картинка прямоугольная? (это подсказка)

Comment: *Алгоритм*?....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575625/how-can-i-read-how-many-pixels-an-image-has-in-python

Comment: Видимо Вам не алгоритм нужен, а какой-то кусок кода.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот как посчитать кол-во пикселей:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575625/how-can-i-read-how-many-pixels-an-image-has-in-python)

```
pip3 install pillow
```

```
from PIL import Image

def get_num_pixels(filepath):
    width, height = Image.open(filepath).size
    return width*height

print(get_num_pixels("/path/to/my/file.jpg"))
```

[Вот как генерировать список](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109422/getting-list-of-pixel-values-from-pil) :

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('1.png')

pixels = list(im.getdata())
width, height = im.size
pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in range(height)]
```